# ASP.NET MVC RequireHttps not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, attributes, requirehttps

I'm using System.Web.MVC v2.0.50727 and can't seem to apply the RequireHttpsAttribute. I can use [OutputCache(...)] for instance, but if I try to use [RequireHttps] I get a missing assembly error.

Is there a later version of mvc 2 out there that includes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no MVC build v2.0.50727.  The RTM build is v2.0.50217.

This problem is sometimes caused by a mismatched MVC + MVC Futures.  If you're using MVC 2 Futures in your site, make sure that its version number is also v2.0.50217.